# Setting Qt font antialiasing rgb

Tags: linux, qt, antialiasing

How can I enable rgb(sub-pixel) font antialiasing in a Qt application on Linux without editing the `~/.fonts.conf` file?

### Here's how it's currently rendering:

[image: current rendering]

### Here's how I want it to look:

[image: desired rendering]

Comment: *Concretely*, what's going wrong?  What have you tried?

Comment: I tried edit propeties of QFont.

Comment: In QT 5.4 this issue is solved!